# PHPUnit Version Trouble - Running in Command-line vs Browser

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

I'm new to unit testing and unit testing in PHP.  I'm using PHP 5.3.8 and PHPUnit 3.7.18. I have a simple math class and math test class:

**Math.php**

```
<?php

class Math {

    protected $val1;
    protected $val2;

    public function set_values($val1, $val2) {
        $this -> val1 = $val1;
        $this -> val2 = $val2;
    }

    public function get_values() {
        return $this -> $val1;
        return $this -> $val2;
    }

    public function add_values() {
        $this -> val1 + $this -> val2 = 5;
        return 5;
    }
}

?>
```

**Math_Test.php**

```
<?php

require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';
require_once 'Math.php';

class Math_Test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    protected $value1;
    protected $value2;

    public function test_add() {

        $math = new Math();

        $expected = 7;
        $actual = $math -> add_values();
        $this -> assertEquals($expected, $actual);

    }

    protected function set_up() {
        $this -> math = new Math();
        $this -> math -> setValues(2, 3);
    }

    protected function tear_down() {
        unset($this -> value1);
        unset($this -> value2);
    }
}

?>
```

At first I was struggling because I have an older version of PHPUnit in my `xampp` installation.  I went through and upgraded PEAR and PHPUnit and was able to get the above test to work.

What's confusing to me is that I can run this test in the command line and get the expected results.  But I was hoping I could run it in the browser too, so I could view results that way.

With my same installation, I can get this similar test to run in my browser just fine (this came from the comment section of `..xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit.php`):

```
<?php

require_once 'PHPUnit.php';

class MathTest extends PHPUnit_TestCase {
    var $fValue1;
    var $fValue2;

    function MathTest($name) {
      $this->PHPUnit_TestCase($name);
    }

    function setUp() {
      $this->fValue1 = 2;
      $this->fValue2 = 3;
    }

    function testAdd() {
      $this->assertTrue($this->fValue1 + $this->fValue2 == 5);
    }
}

$suite = new PHPUnit_TestSuite();
$suite->addTest(new MathTest('testAdd'));

$result = PHPUnit::run($suite);
print $result->toHTML();

?>
```

Notice the use of the newer `Auotloader.php` vs `PHPUnit.php` and `PHPUnit_TestCase` vs `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`.  Maybe the versions are mixed on my system and causing trouble?

How do I run the newer version tests (the first test) in the browser? I'd expect something like where I use the test suite and result classes to run and display in HTML. I've tried variations to no avail.

I tried setting up the print to browser section as in the second test, for the first test and get this error:

`Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit' not found in...`

I confirmed PHPUnit and my `include_path` and everything seems to be working.  Plus, the test runs fine in the terminal...

I have installed VisualPHPUnit and this tool is great for those who want to see visual tests in the browser.  If I can get anywhere with this question, I will probably shift my focus to making VisualPHPUnit work for me.

I've learned a lot writing and editing this question.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: What's your question/problem exactly?

Comment: Added to question... Basically first test throws error. I will add the error soon.

Comment: In the documentation (http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html) says that you should use setUp() and tearDown(), not set_up() and tear_down().
Besides that, in your second test, you are including the file PHPUnit.php. What's the content of that file? I'm asking because maybe you have an older PHPUnit installed in PEAR, and you use that version when you make your test class inherit from PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase. In your second test, by including PHPUnit.php you may be using a newer version

Comment: You don't have the toHTML() call in your first test. Your first file is just a test definition but no php code is being executed. To get output you need to execute something, like you do in your second test with: $result = PHPUnit::run($suite);
print $result->toHTML();

Comment: Yah, already tried that, in the beginning.  I mentioned it in the OQ.  That is part of the problem.  It seems that despite the class TsetSuite existing in the Framework directory of PHPUnit, the browser version with toHTML() is not running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `toHTML()` method is not a part of the newer versions of PHPUnit.  I searched the PHPUnit repository that I use and there seems to be no instance of this function.  I'm thinking that perhaps it was done away with for some reason.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, as that would definitely answer the question.

I am satisfied with running PHPUnit in the terminal and using [VisualPHPUnit](https://github.com/NSinopoli/VisualPHPUnit).